# How to make this Ajax ModalPopUp works with this GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a GridView that shows the suggestions submitted by the users and stored in the database. In the last column, the status will be displayed. I want to make this column to be a clickable and when the Admin clicks on it, a ModalPopUp window (Ajax ModalPopUpExtender) will be viewed with the RadioButtonList that shows the status. I just started with writing the code and I faced many problems. I fixed all of them except one which is the following:

> ***Unknown server tag 'AjaxToolKit:ModalPopUpExtender'***

I don't know how to fix error. **Could you please help me with it?**

My ASP.NET code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
    <asp:TabContainer CssClass="tabCont" ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Height="500px" ScrollBars="Auto" Width="100%">
        <asp:TabPanel ID="All_SafetySuggestions_Tab" HeaderText="All" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
    <strong> Division </strong>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDivision" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
        AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="sqlDataSourceDivision" DataTextField="DivisionShortcut" 
        DataValueField="DivisionShortcut"  
        Width="175px" EnableViewState="False">
        <asp:ListItem Value="%">All</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>


    <br />  <br />  

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
                        width="900px" CssClass="mGrid" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" CssClass="alt" />
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold = "True" ForeColor="Black" Height="20px"/> 
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                    SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
                    SortExpression="Username" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionShortcut" HeaderText="DivisionShortcut" 
                    SortExpression="DivisionShortcut" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />

                <%-- This to make status be opened and edited through the Ajax ModalPopUp Window --%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSuggestionStatus" Text='<%#Eval("Status")%>'
                                        OnClick="lnkSuggestionTitle_Click">
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <%--<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Status" 
                    SortExpression="Status" />--%>
            </Columns>
            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnModalPopUp" style="display:none" />

        <AjaxToolkit:ModalPopUpExtender ID="modalPopUpExtender1"
                                        runat="server" 
                                        TargetControlID="btnModalPopUp" 
                                        PopupControlID="pnlPopUp" 
                                        BackgroundCssClass="popUpStyle"
                                        PopupDragHandleControlID="panelDragHandle" 
                                        OkControlID="OKButton">
        </AjaxToolkit:ModalPopUpExtender>

        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlPopUp">
            <table id="suggestionStatus">
                <tr>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="StatusList" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>Received</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Pending</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Actioned</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Transferred</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <asp:Button ID="confirmButton" runat="server" Text="Confirm" 
                                OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to send an email notification about the safety suggestion to the owner?')" 
                                OnClick="btnSendStatus_Click" />
                </tr>
            </table>
            <asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" Text="Close" />
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT     dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.ID, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Title, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Description, dbo.employee.Name, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username, 
                      dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.SafetySuggestionsType.Type, dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.Status
FROM         dbo.employee INNER JOIN
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Divisions ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode INNER JOIN
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsType ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.TypeID = dbo.SafetySuggestionsType.ID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.StatusID = dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.ID"
                      FilterExpression="[DivisionShortcut] like '{0}%'">

                      <FilterParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision" Name="DivisionShortcut" 
                                                 PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                    </FilterParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSourceDivision" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [DivisionShortcut] FROM [Divisions]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

       </div>
       </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:TabPanel>
```

My C# code-behind:

```
protected void lnkSuggestionStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        modalPopUpExtender1.Show();
    }
```

Also, regarding the RadioButtonList values that will be shown, in the ModalPopUp window, **How can I bind it to the Database?**

For your information, the database design is as following:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name
SafetySuggestionsLog Table: ID, Title, Description, Username, StatusID
SafetySuggestionsStatus Table: ID, Status
```

Comment: Add a reference to the AjaxControlToolkit DLL in your visual studio project. Register the user control with the page using the `<%@ Register ` directive. In the directive you will specify the user control tag prefix for the AjaxControlToolkit. If you already have those elements configured, post your current register directive for the ACT, so we can see if there's a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what you are doing wrong:

You are calling the AJAXControl through its Assembly Name. You should use:

```
    <asp:ModalPopUpExtender />
instead of
    <AjaxToolkit:ModalPopUpExtender />
```

This gonna prbably make Modal Popup Work!